# Help needed in understanding Heron's Formula

Tags: trigonometry, area

So i just started learning Trigonometry seriously and something doesn't feel right to me, either I'm missing something or not but.

Lets assume we have a triangle

[image: Triangle named Jeffrey]]

and there are two ways to find the area.
1 is using the standard $$A = \frac{1}{2}bh$$ and by using the example image above we get $A = 10625$

but if I use the other formula, in this case, Heron's Formula 
\begin{align*}
s & = \frac{a+b+c}{2}\\
A & = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
\end{align*}
the area becomes $A = 10620.09$.

They're both gravely close to each other, which has me thinking maybe I missed something.

So my question is, why are the areas different?

Comment: Heron's formula is exact

Comment: The height is really 124.94

Comment: The calculation was fine, so Paul is probably right.

Comment: @Paul Post as answer? Perhaps the OP is using software that rounds its numerical displays.

Comment: If the side lengths are correct, the area calculated from Heron's formula is correct, too. If you _calculate_ the height from that area, you get $h=124.94\ldots$, and I guess they rounded that to $125$. But then, you get an error in the calculation of the area.

Comment: I just re did the height and found out it really was an error on my end.

Comment: @mvw. With $ a=170$ and  $c=169$ we have $ac\sin B=$ $(2)(10620.09...)$ so the altitude is $a\sin B=$ $(2)(10620.09)/170=124.942...$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't consider the areas different, because the relative difference is smaller than $0.05\%$.

But you can a priori expect an error on the height to be up to $0.5\%$ as some number is truncated to integer. Hence without deeper error calculus, you can't be conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I just had time to construct the scene in [GeoGebra](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Graphics_Tools):

- We add a point $B=(0,0)$ and a point $C=(170,0)$.
- Then we add a circle around $B$ with radius $r_1=169$
  and a circle around $C$ with radius $r_2=137$.
- We use the intersection tool to determine the intersection points $A$ and $D$ (not shown) of the two circles.
- Then we use the polygon tool to create the triangle $ABC$.
- The perpendicular line tool then allows to pick the point $A$ and the line $BC$ to add the line through $A$, perpendicular to the line $BC$
- The intersection tool allows to define the intersection point $E$ by choosing that perpendicular line and the line $BC$.
- Finally we use the measurement tools to add the area of $ABC$, and the length of the segments $BA$, $CA$ and $AE$.

[image: Construction and Measurement with GeoGebra]

It shows that $AE=124.94$, confirming Paul, that the rounded value $125$ is responsible for the difference in calculated area.

Indeed
$$
\frac{170 \cdot 124.94}{2} = 10619.9
$$
and after digging out two more places
$$
\frac{170 \cdot 124.9422}{2} = 10620.087
$$

**Appendix: Determining the height of the triangle:**

We follow the geometric construction, calculating the intersection point $A=(x,y)$ of the two circles:
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 169^2 \\
(x - 170)^2 + y^2 = 137^2
$$
Subtracting the first from the second equation gives
$$
-340 x + 170^2 = 137^2 - 169^2 \iff \\
x = \frac{170^2 + 169^2 - 137^2}{340} = 113.8
$$
So we can e.g. use the first to calculate
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{169^2 - (113.8)^2} = \pm 124.94222664\dotsb
$$